# Dns-leak in QtWebEngine

Tags: qt, security, proxy, dns, qtwebengine

I creating web-browser Qt whith QtWebEngine. And it does not want to resolve dns-requests through proxy.

`QWebEngineSettings::DnsPrefetchEnabled` does not work.

I tried catch them via `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor` didn't work too.

An Example:

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.h

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QWebEnginePage>
#include <QWebEngineProfile>
#include <QWebEngineSettings>
#include <QNetworkProxy>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{

    QNetworkProxy proxy;

    proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);

    proxy.setHostName("proxy_host");
    proxy.setPort(proxy_port);
    proxy.setCapabilities(QNetworkProxy::HostNameLookupCapability);
    //proxy.setUser(user);
    //proxy.setPassword(pass);

    QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);

    QWebEngineProfile *profile = QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile();

    QWebEngineSettings* sett = profile->settings();
    sett->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
    sett->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::XSSAuditingEnabled, false);
    sett->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, true);
    sett->setUnknownUrlSchemePolicy(QWebEngineSettings::AllowAllUnknownUrlSchemes);
    sett->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::DnsPrefetchEnabled, false);

    profile->setUseForGlobalCertificateVerification();

    QWebEngineView *w = new QWebEngineView(this);
    QWebEnginePage *p = new QWebEnginePage(profile,this);
    w->setPage(p);
    w->load(QUrl("https://browserleaks.com/ip"));

    this->setCentralWidget(w);
    this->resize(900,900);

}
```

Comment: Please provide more information / context. Read this so that you can improve your question
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "And it does not want to resolve dns-requests through proxy." what does that mean? There are no  "proxies" in DNS world.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, I want to dns requests from my application to go through a proxy. An example if I set proxy with capability QNetworkProxy::HostNameLookupCapability and hang it to simple QTcpSocket, then QTcpSocket when it resolve hostname (let's say via QAbstractSocket::connectToHost) will send dns requests through a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a local proxy server and using the `--host-resolver-rules` flag (it finally started working at 5.15) referred everything to it. The task is generally solved, but if you know more elegant solutions, you are welcome to my hut.

Comment: I am having the same issue; despite an `HttpProxy` being set at the application-level I am seeing DNS look-ups happen on both the proxy host _and_ the machine running the Qt app.  Using the same proxy with Chrome does not show DNS look-ups on the local machine.  Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @trojanfoe, If you went down the same path as me, then you just need to write flag well. Something like this `--host-resolver-rules=MAP * ~NOTFOUND, EXCLUDE <local server address>`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but where are these flags set?  Is it [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwebengine-debugging.html)?

Comment: @trojanfoe, just command line args